# Disable hardware/device back button but Appbar back button should be enabled

Tags: flutter, back-button

```
WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () => Future.value(allowHardwareBack),  // allowHardwareBack flag to enable/disable
    child: Scaffold(body: Body())
)
```

**What I am getting :** The above code disables the back functionality from device back button and from the Appbar back button as well.

**What I want to acheive :**
The AppBar back button (i.e back arrow leading icon) should be enabled regardless of device back button enabled or disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your own custom back arrow with the help of `leading` property:

```
leading: IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
),
```